# Are different words used for wink and blink?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario, verbos, sinónimos

Does Spanish have different words for **wink** (one eye) & **blink** (both eyes)? What are they? Do I have other options (phrases) to describe eyelid movement?

Comment: "entrecerrar los ojos" = Squint : this is when you squish your eyelids to see clearly

Comment: desorbitar : exaggerated open eyes

Comment: In the blink of an eye = *En un abrir y cerrar de ojos*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it does.

```
wink = guiñar (un ojo)

blink = parpadear
```

from RAE:

> **Guiñar**
>
> Voz expr. del románico occid., quizá del lat. tardío cinnus 'señal que se hace con los ojos'; cf. ceño2.
>
> 1. tr. Cerrar un ojo momentáneamente quedando el otro abierto, a veces con disimulo por vía de señal o advertencia.
> 2. tr. Entornar los párpados ligeramente, por efecto de la luz o por mala visión.
> 3. intr. Mar. Dicho de un buque: Dar guiñadas por mal gobierno, marejada u otra causa, o darlas a propósito por medio del timón.
> 4. prnl. Hacerse guiños o señas con los ojos.
> 5. prnl. germ. Irse, huir.

and

> **Parpadear**
>
> 1. intr. Abrir y cerrar repetidamente los párpados.
> 2. intr. Dicho de la luminosidad de un cuerpo o de una imagen: Vacilar u oscilar.

Some other verbs related to eye movement can be `bizquear` (Padecer estrabismo o simularlo.)

But, as you can see, I've included the whole set of meanings of "guiñar", I think that's what you request, altough they are not as widely used as meanings 1 & 4.

Comment: Como sinónimos también podemos encontrar pestañeo. y guiño también puede usarse como traducción de hint o hinting.

Comment: In Colombia we use "matar el ojo" as to wink.

Answer (score 3):

Also [**pestañear**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SoTR1Wq)

> 1. intr. Mover los párpados.

and [**entornar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=FjDN7Gn)

> 2. tr. Cerrar los ojos de manera incompleta.

Considering more technical words there is also [**blefaroespasmo**](https://www.blepharospasm.org/spanish1.pdf)

> El blefaroespasmo es un tipo de distonía focal que consiste en el **cierre involuntario de los párpados**. El cierre es intenso, crónico, y **bilateral (afecta ambos ojos)**.

[**ptosis**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptosis_palpebral)

> un descenso permanente del párpado superior

Answer (score 1):

Also [**cucar**](https://dle.rae.es/cucar):

> 1. tr. guiñar (‖ cerrar un ojo momentáneamente). = *wink*

and [**bornear <sup>2</sup>**](https://dle.rae.es/bornear#5uyx3SR):

> 1. tr. Mirar con un solo ojo, teniendo el otro cerrado, para examinar si un cuerpo o varios están en una misma línea con otro u otros, o si una superficie tiene alabeo.

and [**turnio**](https://dle.rae.es/turnio?):

> 1. adj. Dicho de los ojos o de la mirada: Estrábicos o torcidos.
> 2. adj. Dicho de una persona: Que tiene los ojos turnios. U. t. c. s.

Comment: ¡bienvenido!. Gracias por tu excelente respuesta. Muchos aprenderemos de estas palabras tan poco usadas.

Answer (score 0):

Una alternativa más: [**bizquear**](https://dle.rae.es/bizquear?)

> 2. tr. guiñar (‖ cerrar un ojo momentáneamente).  *= wink*